# When I enter itempurchased and price it does not calculate total amount and instead shows default values(0.00)

Tags: java, methods

I am learning Java. Here I created **two classes**: one for *methods* and second is *main*. When I enter the price and item, it shows only the default value (0.00) and does not perform the **multiplication** I wanted it to.

The classes are declared below:

```
public class InvoiceTest {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {   
        Invoice i = new Invoice("","",0,0.0);     // Invoice
        double am = 0.0;
        Scanner ab = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.printf("Enter the num of item you purchased:");
        int itempurch =ab.nextInt();

        System.out.printf("Enter the amount of item:");
        double price = ab.nextDouble();

        System.out.printf("%nInvoice amount is: %.2f", am);
        i.am(am);
    }
}

public class Invoice {
    private String partnum;    // instances variables
    private String partdescp;
    private int itempurch;
    private double price;

    public Invoice(String partnum, String partdescp, int itempurch, double price) {   
        this.partnum = partnum;
        this.itempurch = itempurch;
        this.partdescp = partdescp;
        this.price = price;  
    }

    public void am(double am) {
        if (itempurch < 0)
            itempurch = 0;        
        else if (price < 0)
            price = 0.0;
        else 
            am = itempurch * price;
    }

    public void setpartnum(String partnum) {
        this.partnum = partnum;    
    }

    public void setitempurch(int itempurch) {
        this.itempurch = itempurch;
    } 

    public void setpartdescp(String partdescp) {
        this.partdescp = partdescp;   
    }

    public void setprice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getpartnum() {
        return partnum;
    }

    public int getitempurch() {
        return itempurch;
    }

    public String getpartdescp() {
        return partdescp;
    }

    public double getprice() {
        return price;
    }
}
```

Comment: I assuming you talking about `am` variable. If so, you never changed its value.

Comment: Please format your code correctly. After all, you can't expect us to help if you dump a bunch of code into a box.

Comment: Also, codestyle-wise. If you add getters and setters, please read up more on Java-Bean notation: correct getter and setter name include capitalized property name, not lowercase one. It's also far better to read that way.

Comment: what should I do to solve it? @M. Prokhorov

Comment: Well, you have to do whatever calculation you wanted with it and then assign new value to `am`.

Answer (score 0):

In your `main` method, you define local variables `itempurch` and `price`. Keep in mind that these variables are only visible within the `main` method! In order to work with your `Invoice` instance, you need to tell it that some values for `itempurch` and `price` have been set. You do this with your setters.

You can now get the value of `am`. Never change input values of your methods!
Instead try something like

```
public double getAm() {
    int itemPurchInternal = Math.max(itempurch,0);
    double priceInternal = Math.max(price,0.0);
    return itemPurchInternal * priceInternal;        
}
```

in your Invoice class. This way you do not change your values for `itempurch` and `price` and still get a result.